# How to create function near DATE by today - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, compare

I have this variable:

```
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // for example today is 2015-10-04 12:30:00
$first_date = "2015-10-01 00:00:00";
$second_date = "2015-10-02 00:00:00";
$third_date = "2015-10-03 00:00:00";
$fourth_date = "2015-10-04 00:00:00";
$fift_date = "2015-10-06 00:00:00";
```

//place the function - and result to $output
$output = "result";

And I need this. If variable of any day is the nearliest to $today from PAST date, set $output = 1; ... If date is in BEFORE $today - ignor thi variable.

### Anyone know?

For better understanding - 
I have a DATE in database like this in rows:

1. ID_product = 4; ID_special_price = 20; from = 2015-10-03 00:00:00; to = 2017-04-30 00:00:00;
2. ID_product = 4; ID_special_price = 21; from = 2015-10-03 00:00:00; to = 2015-10-04 00:00:00;
3. ID_product = 4; ID_special_price = 22; from = 2015-10-04 00:00:00; to = 2015-10-05 00:00:00;
4. ID_product = 4; ID_special_price = 23; from = 2015-10-05 00:00:00; to = 2015-10-07 00:00:00;

So this is a special price from(start) and to(end). In my case, I need to foreach  ID_product 4 times and pick up only one row - now it will be row number 3. with ID_special_price = 22, becose this DATE - from(2015-10-04 00:00:00) today (2015-10-04 12:30:00) to(2015-10-05 00:00:00) is the nearest "to" actually date and still active, becose end of this special offer ending 2015-10-05 00:00:00.

Comment: Any code that you tried yet? Which of the dates should your algorithm return? (The description is hard to understand.) Why not use an array of dates instead of multiple variables? And it certainly would be easier working with timestamps instead of date strings.

Comment: Please, rephrase your question because it's difficult to understand what you really need.
As @mario said It's better to use something like this: $dates = array('2015-10-01 00:00:00', '2015-10-02 00:00:00', '2015-10-03 00:00:00', '2015-10-04 00:00:00', '2015-10-06 00:00:00');